# Windows 8 metro app: styling a button dynamically. C# and Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a xaml page with Gridview which has a Button.I am using a grouped Item page. The buttons are generated based on the dataset returned.
10 records will display 10 buttons.

```
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  >                      
                                <Button  Click="ItemView_ItemClick">
                                        <StackPanel Margin="5" >
                                        <TextBlock Tag="cntCustName" Style="{ThemeResource CntNormalTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding CUSTOMERNAME }"/>
                                        <TextBlock Tag="cntCatCode" Style="{ThemeResource CntLrgTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding CATEGORYCODE}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Tag="cntDay" Style="{ThemeResource CntNormalTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding DAY}"/>                               
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

I am getting data in a foreach loop. I want to be able to assign the styles of the buttons
dynamically based on some criteria which I have.

```
        foreach (ContactData ContactData in _openContatcs)
                    {
                        if (ContactData.CFLAG)
                        {
                            //this is an example
                            Application.Current.Resources["contactSquare"] = ampStyle;
                        }
                        group.Items.Add(ContactData);
                    }


        Styles are defined like this in a folder: Assests/Resources/BaseAPStyles.xaml

        <Style x:Name="contactSquare" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="160"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid Background="#ffffc600">
                                <ContentPresenter>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

My buttons are not showing the styles. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use `x:key="contactSqaure"` to find the style in the application resources.

Then, access the button you would like to style and assign the style to the button like this.

```
yourButton.Style = Application.Resources.Current["contactSqaure"] as Style;
```

You can also define styles in C#, or edit the button's dependency properties.

```
yourButton.Height = 160;
yourButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

you can access the button in your datatemplate when it loads.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Loaded="Button_Loaded" .../>
....

void Button_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    (sender as Button).Style = yourStyle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I am unable to access the button directly. I think it is because it is in a DataTemplate in a gridview. I am unable to get the property of the button. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Is each Gridview item going to have a different Button Style? If so, what determines which style to use? Have you looked into using a data template selector?